# Loading game data into pool without globals

Tags: c++, multithreading, global

I am writing a text-based game available through TELNET for my own amusement in C++. I created a class hierarchy based on game aspects/components such as Vehicles, Pedestrians, Players, Vehicles, Bikes, etc.

I am thinking of implementing a "Pool" object which would store pointers to the specific loaded elements. I'm thinking of using an *Add()* function in the pool which would overload based on the class of the element I would like to add to the pool. The problem is the following: suppose I want to have this element pool (or some layer on top of it) available all the time. Perhaps I need a function *GetAllVehicles()* (just a quick example) which would look through the pool data and return me all the vehicles in an array with a bunch of pointers.

The thing is, what if I wanted to go through this pool somewhere in my code. Inherently, the Pool object should be a *global* in some sense because you want to access your loaded game elements everywhere without having to pass the created object around for eternity. However, I don't want it to pollute the global namespace and I want multi-threading so declaring a global variable would be an especially bad idea.

The question is simple: what should I do to make this work?

Comment: Is the pool (and the objects in this pool) going to be immutable?  If so (or if you can make them so, e.g. by setting them up at startup and promising never to modify them afterwards), then the read-only access from multiple threads won't be a problem.  As for polluting the global namespace, you can always declare them in a separate namespace if you want to.

Comment: How about [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to create an instance in your `main` function and pass the instance to every function where it is used or pass to the constructors of objects that require the pool.

Another possibility is the Singleton design pattern.

There are flaming dragons on both sides of the issue (Singleton vs. passing the object).  Choose your own poison.